# Iterating over results of PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to run a query using PDO, based on data in the URL paramater (yes, I know that this is prone to attacks, but its internal code for a utility).

```
$user = 'USER';
$pass = 'PASSWORD';
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=PRODUCTS;host=HOST'; 

try {
    $productDB = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass); 
    $productDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $msg = 'PDO ERROR' . $e->getFile() . ' L.' . $e->getLine() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();
    die($msg);
}
if(isset($_GET['cat'])) 
{
    $cat = $_GET['cat'];
    print "cat = $cat <br>";
    $products = $productDB->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id LIKE ?');
    $products->execute(array($cat));
    $rows = $products->rowCount();
    print "$rows rows returned";
?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>product_id</td>
    <td>product_name</td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($products->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $id = $row['product_id'];
    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    print "<tr>";
    print "<th scope=\"row\"><b>$id</b></th>";
    print "<td> $product_name </td>";
    print "<tr>";
    }
print "</table>";
}
?>
```

When I run this code, it prints the correct number of rows depending on the query, but does not populate the table.

I have also tried replacing the `prepare` and `execute` lines with:

```
$products = $productDB->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id LIKE $cat");
```

Which returns the correct row count, but doesn't otherwise help.

And finally, I've tried replacing the foreach line with something like:

```
$rows = $products->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

My attempts to do the same with a fixed query all work fine, but I am having trouble working out how to place a variable element in a query, and then iterate over the results.

Comment: If you're using placeholders as in your first example this shouldn't be vulnerable to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). In your second example where you have `$cat` in the string, you *are* vulnerable. Don't do this. Attacks happen because of injecting unescaped data. Using placeholders will ensure it's escaped properly, so it's best to use then whenever you can, and be extra careful in those rare cases when you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (If I understood correctly) :

```
$products = $productDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id LIKE :cat");

// Now, you can either do this :
$products->bindParam('cat', '%'.$cat.'%');
$products->execute();

// or you can call execute with an associative array of your parameterized query.
$products->execute(array('cat' => '%'.$cat.'%'));

// Then, get all the results like this :
$rows = $products->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Do work here ..
}

// Or, like this :
while ($row = $products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Do work here ..
}
```

I personaly prefer the while, because you don't fetch the whole query in one var, reducing the amount of memory needed.

I also recommend you to use the [FETCH_*](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php) parameter, to get only the kind of array you want.

By the way, you need to know that [rowCount](http://php.net/pdostatement.rowCount) should not be used to count the rows returned by a SELECT. As said by php.net :

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Comment: For a parameterized query, I think I need to use `prepare` and `execute`, no? When I run it like this, it does not execute beyond the `query` line. 

I did try the idea of placing the `fetchAll()` outside the `foreach`, but it did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Oups, sorry, I went too fast! Yes, it's that, you have to prepae your request.

Comment: There, I improved my answer ;)

Comment: There are 2 essential things about web-application: 1. data size is relatively small, to fit a web page of reasonable size. 2. A good application always fetches it's all data first, and only then starts output, using a *template.*

Comment: You are correct... in theory. Data size isn't really small. You manage to make it small. If you have a list of 1M users, you wont load all of them in your page, you will load the 30 most used, or something like that. The query shown in the question, `SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id LIKE $cat` can returns millions of entries, load them in one object, and have fun.

Comment: Thanks, the `while` was exactly what I was looking for, a way to load the results one at a time.

Comment: `fetchAll()` should only be used if 1. You are using one of its special flags to construct a specific and non-standard result sets or 2. You are not intending on iterating the data in the same layer/method.  When your code will immediately iterate just fetch each row as you iterate.

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything to store the result:

```
$products->execute(array($cat));
```

needs to go in a variable:

```
$result = $products->execute(array($cat));
```

Then, instead of calling `$products->fetchAll()`, use `$results->fetchAll()`:

```
foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $row)
```

I find it easier to use a `$query` variable (for `prepare`, etc) and then get the result into something like `$result` or `$product`. Makes the code a bit easier to read.

Comment: I was fairly sure that the `->execute()` method did not return data, it simply changes the state of the PDO object and makes it receptive to `fetchAll()` and such. Nonetheless, I did try this. In this case, the program did not indicate that any rows were present in the `$result` variable, when tested with `->rowCount()`, so I'm not sure this is what I need.

Comment: `fetchAll()` should only be used if 1. You are using one of its special flags to construct a specific and non-standard result sets or 2. You are not intending on iterating the data in the same layer/method.  When your code will immediately iterate just fetch each row as you iterate.